# jQuery collision detection working fine for only first item, newly created div of same class does not register in collision detection function

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a game where Cartman catches the falling cheesy poofs and you earn 5 points per catch. I have my collision detection working perfectly for the first drop. I remove that cheesyPoof. Meanwhile, I have a setInterval going to create new cheesyPoofs, assigning the same class (which is called in the collision function. Those new cheesyPoofs, despite getting the same class do not register in the collision function for some reason. It's clearly getting the same class because it's following the CSS rules. Hope someone can help!

```
const cheesyPoofs = $('.item');
const cartman = $('#catcher');
// window.setInterval(function () {
//   let cheesyPoofs = $('.item');
// }, 100);
let counter = 0;

// collission detection
function collision(cheesyPoofs, cartman) {
  // define full dimensions of cheesypoofs
  let x1 = $(cheesyPoofs).offset().left;
  let y1 = $(cheesyPoofs).offset().top;
  let cheesyWidth = $(cheesyPoofs).outerWidth(true);
  let cheesyHeight = $(cheesyPoofs).outerHeight(true);
  let box1 = x1 + cheesyWidth;
  let top1 = y1 + cheesyHeight;
  // define full dimensions of cartman
  let x2 = $(cartman).offset().left;
  let y2 = $(cartman).offset().top;
  let cartmanWidth = $(cartman).outerWidth(true);
  let cartmanHeight = $(cartman).outerHeight(true);
  let box2 = x2 + cartmanWidth;
  let top2 = y2 + cartmanHeight;
  // all measurements of when cartman and cheesypoofs are not colliding, return false
  if (top1 < y2 || y1 > top2 || box1 < x2 || x1 > box2) {
    return false;
  } else { // collision
    console.log("COLLISION!!!")
    return true;
  }
};

//randomize a left property for the new cheesypoof css
let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 10 + 1)) + 10;

//check for collision every 20 miliseconds, if collision is true, add 5 to counter and remove cheesypoofs
window.setInterval(function() {
  if (collision(cheesyPoofs, cartman) === true) {
    counter += 5;
    $('#counter').text(counter);
    $(cheesyPoofs).remove();
    $(cheesyPoofs).css({
    left: randomLeft,
    });
  } if (counter === 50) {
    $('.winMessage').addClass('.winMessage2');
  }
}, 20);

function newPoofs() {
  let item = $('<div />');
  $(item).appendTo('.gameboard');
  $(item).attr('class', 'item');
  let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (650 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
  $(item).css({
    left: randomLeft,
    })
   console.log(item);
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  newPoofs();
}, 3000);

<!-- heres the HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cartman Adventure</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<audio class="audio" id="yes-audio" controls preload="none">
  <source src="cheesypoofs.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<h1>Yea, I want cheesy poofs!</h1>
<h2>An Eric Cartman Adventure</h2>
<div class="gameboard">
  <h3 class="score">Score:</h3>
  <div id="counter">0</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="catcher" id="catcher"></div>
  <div class="winMessage"></div>
</div>


<script src="src/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/app.js"></script>
<script src= "src/game.js"></script>
<script src= "src/item.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

/* And heres the CSS */

.gameboard {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 5px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: southpark;
  src: url("southpark.ttf");
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: southpark;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: southpark;
}
.score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 30px;
}
#counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 5px;
}
.item {
  height: 90px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url("images/cheesypoofs.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  animation: fall 3s infinite;
  transition: all linear;
  left: 50px;
}
@keyframes fall {
  0% {top: 0;}
  /*5% {top: 20px;}
  10% {top: 50px;}
  25% {top: 100px;}*/
  /*50% {top: 150px;}*/
  /*75% {top: 200px;}
  90% {top: 250px;}*/
  100% {top: 350px;}
}
.catcher {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-image: url("images/cartman.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.catcher .move {
  right: 100px;
}
.winMessage {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  top: -500px;
  right: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.winMessage2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 200px;
  right: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.audio {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Just from your question title, it sounds like you're having a problem because javascript reads the initial DOM.  You'll have to look into binding (reading the whole thing now).  It looks like you never update your `cheesyPoofs` item to be the latest

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip, I'll look into binding. I'm unfamiliar with the concept right now (very new to Javascript... like 3 weeks new :)

Comment: Are you using JQuery with Typescript?

Comment: No, I'm not using that

Comment: It looks like whenever you spawn a new item, you need to make that item equal to `cheesyPoofs`, then run your collision detection again

Comment: Hm, ok, I've tried a couple things in the newPoofs function and in the spawn setInterval. Do I run the collision detection again right after that? I currently have my collision detection function running on a setInterval as well

Comment: You'll have to run whatever function fires the cheesypoof right after you replace the cheesypoofs variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble following. I've tried a few things to no avail.

Comment: function newPoofs() {
  let item = $('<div />');
  $(item).appendTo('.gameboard');
  $(item).attr('class', 'item');
  let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (650 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
  $(item).css({
    left: randomLeft,
    })
  return item;
}


window.setInterval(function() {
  newPoofs();
  let cheesyPoofs = item;
}, 3000);

Comment: function newPoofs() {
  let item = $('<div />');
  $(item).appendTo('.gameboard');
  $(item).attr('class', 'item');
  let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (650 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
  $(item).css({
    left: randomLeft,
    })
  let cheesyPoofs = item;
}


window.setInterval(function() {
  newPoofs();
}, 3000);

Comment: Are you able to put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: yea, I'll do that now and send you link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khuy5ja4/1/

Comment: it was tough to put it in there because I have three separate javascript files all linked, item.js (which has the newPoofs function and the setInterval creating new poofs), game.js (which has all the collision logic and point increase), and app.js (which creates the keyboard functionality).

Comment: Check my profile and send me a message. I'd like to help you with a bit more theory and hopefully a little better logic.

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate it. Just sent you an email.